# Application crashes after splash screen on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

My Firemonkey app crashes after the splash screen on a iPad with iOS 8.4. Using XCode's instruments the closest thing I can find ito error is: 
`Runtime error 217 at 00000001974D5378`.

However everything works perfectly on my iPhone 4 with iOS 8.4 and iOS simulator.

My Iphone 4 is a **32 bit** device, and the iPad a **64 bit**. I get the same result if I do a 64 bit compile only or building a universal binary.

Using Delphi XE8 Update 1, XCode 6.4

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using "Standard Architectures"...

Comment: Yes, very simple and small application. I deploy a few images and employ 2 custom fonts.

Comment: Without a full symbolicated crash report and related code, it is impossible to even have an idea what this could be about.

Comment: This is the weird thing. I do not get a crash report, that is normally accessed from the XCode Device's Window. As soon as I do get some sort of report I will post it.

Comment: @WillemvanZyl on iPad -- try to run your app not via PAServer. make application bundle and try to run directly from iPad. you will see console with a messages.